# How to make Flutter work on WSL2 using host's emulator?

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, adb, android-sdk-manager

This issue was a headache, so I wish to share my solution. It starts installing requirements for Android SDK (without installing Android Studio), Dart and Flutter, and it finalizes running a Flutter app on Windows host.

==================

## on WSL2

==================

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

#### Installing Dart

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
$ sudo sh -c 'wget -qO- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -'
$ sudo sh -c 'wget -qO- https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dart_stable.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list'
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install dart
$ echo "export PATH=\"/usr/lib/dart/bin:$PATH\"" >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.barshrc 
$ dart --version
Dart VM version: 2.8.4 (stable) (Unknown timestamp) on "linux_x64"
```

===>>> ***Note**: The Dart SDK is [bundled with](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#run-flutter-doctor) Flutter*

#### Installing Android SDK

Get [Command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools) for Android (Linux) only.

```
$ sudo apt install -y lib32z1 default-jdk git unzip zip
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ unzip commandlinetools-linux-6609375_latest.zip
$ rm commandlinetools-linux-6609375_latest.zip
$ mkdir -p Android/cmdline-tools
$ mv tools/ Android/cmdline-tools/
$ mv Android/ ~/Programs/
```

Append the following lines to `.bashrc` file:

```
# Android
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Programs/Android
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/lib:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator:$PATH

# Java
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Continue the installation

```
$ cd ~
$ source .bashrc
$ sdkmanager --version
    4.0.1
$ sdkmanager --list
$ sdkmanager --install "system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-29" "build-tools;29.0.3"
$ sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
$ sdkmanager --update
$ sdkmanager --list | sed -e '/^$/q'
$ sdkmanager --licenses
```

Accept all licenses.

#### Installing Flutter

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ wget https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_1.17.5-stable.tar.xz
$ cd ~/Programs
$ tar xf ~/Downloads/flutter_linux_1.17.5-stable.tar.xz
$ cd ~
$ echo "export PATH=$HOME/Programs/flutter/bin:$PATH" >> .bashrc
$ source .bashrc
$ flutter --version
Flutter 1.17.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 8af6b2f038 (11 days ago) • 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
Engine • revision ee76268252
Tools • Dart 2.8.4
$ flutter config --android-sdk $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
```

#### Creating the emulator

```
$ cd ~
$ curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
$ source .sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh
$ sdk v
    SDKMAN 5.8.3+506
$ sdk install gradle 6.5.1
$ gradle -v
$ avdmanager list
$ echo "no" | avdmanager --verbose create avd --force --name "generic_10" --package "system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86" --tag "google_apis" --abi "x86"
```

Add/Modify these lines in `~/.android/avd/generic_10.avd/config.ini` file:

```
skin.name=1080x1920
hw.lcd.density=480
hw.keyboard=yes
```

Check emulator created:

```
$ emulator -list-avds
```

==================

## on Windows 10

==================

```
> Get-ComputerInfo -Property "WindowsProductName"
Windows 10 Pro
> Get-ComputerInfo -Property "WindowsVersion"
2004
> Get-ComputerInfo -Property "OsBuildNumber"
19041
> Get-ComputerInfo -Property "OsArchitecture"
64-bit
> Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias Ethernet|findstr IPAddress
IPAddress         : 192.168.0.29
```

#### Installing Android SDK

Get [Command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools) for Android (Windows) only.

The steps to follow are basically the same as in the ***Installing Android SDK on WSL2*** section, you can read [this page](https://cloudreports.net/install-android-sdk-on-windows-10-without-android-studio/) for reference if any doubt.

#### Creating the emulator

To install **Gradle** in Windows, follow the instructions in [this page](https://gradle.org/install/).
The rest of the steps are the same as in the ***Creating the emulator on WSL2*** section, where `~` points out your home folder in Windows.

#### Preparing host for listening

You can use any port with `adb` and `emulator` tools, but it is more simple if they manage it by themselves using their default ports. For `adb` tool its default port is 5037. `IP Helper` service uses that port (in my case), so I had to [stop it](https://www.howto-connect.com/disable-enable-ip-helper-service-windows-10-iphlpsvc/).

Open a terminal and check the status of port 5037:

```
> netstat -aon|findstr 5037
```

Run these commands:

```
> adb kill-server
> adb -a -P 5037 nodaemon server
```

Open another terminal (don't close the previous one) and run:

```
> emulator -avd generic_10
```

Open another terminal (don't close the previous ones) and run:

```
> adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

==================

## on WSL2

==================

#### Working with host's `adb`

```
$ echo "export ADB_SERVER_SOCKET=tcp:192.168.0.29:5037" >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

#### Running our Flutter app

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Linux, locale C.UTF-8)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
$ flutter create hello_world
$ cd hello_world
$ flutter run
```

==================

## Observations

==================

- It takes a little longer to build/run the app for first time
- VSCode (remote) can detect this connected device, but it cannot deploy correctly to emulator, so it's better to run the app on terminal
- You cannot use "*hot reload*" features with flutter app because the process of deployment/running never finishes, however the package did be installed and running in your emulator, but for any changes in source code, you need re-run the app.
- This operation consumes too much memory (~90%). There's a [workaround](https://medium.com/@lewwybogus/how-to-stop-wsl2-from-hogging-all-your-ram-with-docker-d7846b9c5b37) to respect. My configuration is:

.

```
[wsl2]    
memory=4GB # Limits VM memory in WSL 2 to 4 GB
swap=0
```

====================

## Pages consulted

====================

- https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux
- [Flutter with WSL 2](https://itnext.io/flutter-with-wsl-2-69ba8fc7682f)
- [Android Command line tools sdkmanager always shows: Warning: Could not create settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440509/android-command-line-tools-sdkmanager-always-shows-warning-could-not-create-se)
- [How to Install Flutter Without Android Studio on Ubuntu](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-install-flutter-without-android-studio-on-ubuntu-6d8b55741afa)
- [Install and Create Emulators using AVDMANAGER and SDKMANAGER](https://gist.github.com/mrk-han/66ac1a724456cadf1c93f4218c6060ae)
- [Building a react native app in WSL2](https://gist.github.com/bergmannjg/461958db03c6ae41a66d264ae6504ade)
- [Using the Android emulator on Windows 10 with WSL2](https://medium.com/@pellea/using-the-android-emulator-on-windows-10-with-wsl2-39c2bae30c49)
- [Developing Flutter with VSCode and WSL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441350/developing-flutter-with-vscode-and-wsl2)
- [Using ADB with WSL2](https://medium.com/@pellea/using-adb-with-wsl2-7aebbb070a47)
- [ADB](https://www.litets.com/article/2019/5/15/401.html)
- [Android Debug Bridge (adb)](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)
- [How to use adb over TCPIP connect?](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/How-to-use-adb-over-TCPIP-connect)
- [Running React Native in WSL with the emulator running directly in Windows](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/58229368.shtml)
- [How can I deploy and execute an application on a device connected to a remote system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245597/how-can-i-deploy-and-execute-an-application-on-a-device-connected-to-a-remote-sy)
- [Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55286542/kotlin-could-not-find-the-required-jdk-tools-in-the-java-installation)
- [Android Studio installs without sdkmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460429/android-studio-installs-without-sdkmanager)

Comment: very esaustive and nice walkthrough to setup flutter + vscode on linux,... but what are the benefits of running flutter on wsl rather than on windows 10?

Comment: I like Linux because it lets me make tasks on command line more easily. You *could* do the same on Windows Terminal BUT it is not so powerful and ease-of-use like Linux terminal. So WSL seemed attractive and I tried to work Flutter over there, it did not turn out as expected. At present I'm working on Linux distro (Manjaro) only.

Comment: regardless the os personal preference, I felt its a bit of a stretch to use WSL to run an android emulator  _inside_ another emulator.. then I am here cause I also set up bash as my default shell on windows and launched flutter from there :)

Comment: There are a number of changes that need to be made to this answer but since the edit que is full:

Comment: change mkdir -p Android/cmdline-tools to  mkdir -p ~/Programs/Android/cmdline-tools/tools

Answer (score 4):

> You cannot use "hot reload" features with flutter app because the process of deployment/running never finishes

Actually, you can! Just connect to the device with `adb connect <IP>` instead of going through the socket. See my full blog post here:

https://dnmc.in/2021/01/25/setting-up-flutter-natively-with-wsl2-vs-code-hot-reload/

Answer (score 1):

If you are like me you had a lot of issues getting adb to work. You need to make sure that windows host and the linux image both have the same version of adb. Following this guide https://www.androidexplained.com/install-adb-fastboot/#update helped me update adb on windows.